# Why is Tk() and StringVar() capitalized

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

Is there a specific reason that Tk() has a capital T rather than a lowercase one?

Comment: They're _classes_, why wouldn't they be?

Answer (score 1):

Per PEP8, [classes should be named using CapWords](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

Same for [type variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#type-variable-names).